# Displaying trailing zeros to right of decimal in label using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

is there a way I can get zeros to show up in my label when they come to the right of a decimal in a number such a s 270.00? I'm trying to display two decimals in all my numerical labels, but QGIS automatically removes trailing zeros.

I've included a snapshot of my attribute table showing a column that i specified the precision to 2, and it shows 680.00, like I want it. But when labeling, these zeros aren't included.

[image]

Comment: Hi Emily, It always helps if you state the version of the software. Some features may not be available in previous versions of qGIS.

Answer (score 2):

With qGIS 2.8.1., on the formatting tab of the label tool (also on the layer properties) you can define to format numbers and show decimal places.
[image]